# Interpolating Z depth in a interpolated perspective orthographic viewing frustum

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering

To interpolate between perspective and orthographic projection I'm using the following formula (which works great because the clipping planes align perfectly):

```
 X' = rw + X / ((Z * fwi - ox) * (1f - a) + ox);
 Y' = rh + Y / ((Z * fhi - oy) * (1f - a) + oy);
```

Where:
rw or rh is (renderWidth or Height - 1) / 2f,
ox is vSize / rw, oy is hSize / rh,
fwi is tan(vFOV/2) / rw, fhi is tan(hFOV/2) / rh, 
a is lerp coefficient; 0 = perspective, 1 = orthographic, 0.5 = in between.

Now to correctly calculate the Z depth in for each fragment, I'm calculating z = 1/z before interpolating it in screen space via a ScanLine function, and finally calculating the true depth at the end via 1/z.

However orthographic projection does not require this depth correction, so I was wondering whats the correct way to determine the true Z, when the projection is being blended.
The current XYZ to XY formula can be summarized via:

[image: formula]

Currently I'm interpolating UV coords via the Depth and it is clearly incorrect when the projection is in between perspective and orthographic. When it reaches 1, it bypasses the 1/z depth correction.

[image]

Please note that this is a software renderer, so performance is quite important. Ideally I would like to be doing the same thing OpenGL is doing in these types of situations.

Comment: `VERTEX_DATA` is not part of any OpenGL shader syntax, so it is unclear what you're using. It is also unclear how you calculate your "mixed perspective". Conceptually, blending between perspective and ortho projection can be interpreted as moving the projectiuon center towards infinity, and all intermediate steps are still simply projective transforms. In such case, there is nothing the GL's automatic perspective correction could not deal with. It is totally unclear why you manually divide by `z`. The real solution is to properly work with the homogeneous `w` coordinate.

Comment: So when OpenGL blends between perspective and orthographic projection, is it really just moving the camera super far back and lowering the FOV until it reaches near zero, and then swapping to orthographic projection?

Comment: No. OpenGL doesn't care. _You_ just transform the coordinates as you see fit, and the effect you seem to be wanting can be represented by a standard 4x4 homogeneous projection matrix

Answer (score 1):

Although the method I used to interpolate probably won't be used by anyone, the math behind it can be.

My clipping plane formula can be described as:
[image: Formula]

Where o = Base Size, a = Base FOV, l = 0 to 1
It is based on the y axis to allow FOV = 0 clipping.

When setting the FOV really small and setting the Z very far back, a orthographic projection can be faked thanks to the tiny 1/z tangent. However I couldn't use a dolly zoom formula as I had already implemented a custom XYZ to XY system.

So all I had to do was offset the Z value by some number.

Looking at dolly zoom clipping plane graphs, it became obvious that the Z offset had to be the Y intercept.

[image: Graph]
With dolly zoom the vertex Z is offset rather than the actual clipping slope but my XYZ to XY method required to offset the clipping slopes.

Reversing the formula to solve for 0 gives (*-1 for y intercept):

[image: Formula]

And then finally the Z correction can be calculated:

[image: Formula]

And with the Z offset added the depth is being now correctly interpolated:

[image: Demo]